# Only apply VBA code to e-mails containing "string" in the subject

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using a code that works great - the purpose is to send info from Outlook to Excel so I can filter it and automatize the work.

The problem is: the VBA code is executing for all e-mails received and I only want to execute it onto e-mails with subject starting with "EK".

I already tried using InStr function as below, but it doesn't work:

```vb
If InStr(xMailItem.Subject, "EK") = 0 Then
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Where should I put this line of code?

```vb
Private Sub GMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xExcelFile As String
    Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xNextEmptyRow As Integer
    Dim linhas As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim linhaInicial As Long
    Dim numeroCaracteresAssunto As Integer
    Dim assuntoEmail As String
    Dim k As Integer
           
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Item.Class <> olMail) Then Exit Sub
    Set xMailItem = Item
    
    xExcelFile = "EXCELFILEPATH.xlsx"
    If IsWorkBookOpen(xExcelFile) = True Then
        Set xExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        Set xWb = GetObject(xExcelFile)
        If Not xWb Is Nothing Then xWb.Close True
    Else
        Set xExcelApp = New Excel.Application
    End If
                              
    Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)
    Set xWs = Sheets.Add
    numeroCaracteresAssunto = Len(xMailItem.Subject)
    assuntoEmail = Right(xMailItem.Subject, numeroCaracteresAssunto - 16)
    xWs.Name = UCase(assuntoEmail)
    xNextEmptyRow = xWs.Range("B" & xWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    linhaInicial = 1
    
    With xWs
        linhas = Split(xMailItem.Body, vbNewLine)
        
        For i = 0 To UBound(linhas)
            Cells(linhaInicial + i, 1).Value = linhas(i)
            linhaInicial = linhaInicial + 1
        Next
        
        For k = 1 To i

            xWs.Range("B" & k).FormulaLocal = "=SEERRO(ÍNDICE($A$1:$A$999;MENOR(SE(ÉNÚM(LOCALIZAR(""PC"";$A$1:$A$999));CORRESP(LIN($A$1:$A$999);LIN($A$1:$A$999)));" & k & "));"""")"
            xWs.Range("B" & k).FormulaArray = xWs.Range("B" & k).Formula
        
        Next k
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you mean to catch `Subject` values that *start with* a given string, why not use the `Left` function instead of `InStr`, which is going to look at the substring *anywhere in the subject* - note that `InStr` returns an *index* indicating *where in the string* it found a match, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Instr` is not case sensitive.

```vb
If InStr(UCase(xMailItem.Subject), UCase("EK")) = 0 Then
```

Either `UCase` or `LCase`.

On both parts, or you may run into an "eK" typo.